# Are Apple boot camp drivers excellent on Windows 7?

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, bootcamp

First off, I realize some may not prefer Windows, but I like Windows, and I like Apple's hardware so let's set aside any preferences on OS and focus on how well I can expect Boot Camp to run for me.

I'm considering purchasing a macbook for my upcoming graduation. I'm stuck between the 13" air and the 13" pro with retina. Either way, I'm planning on getting the 256GB model with 8GB of RAM. I also plan on dual booting with Windows 7. I can't find a reference that comments on how well Apple's Windows drivers work to make the multi touch trackpad work as well in Windows as it does on OS X.

Will I be sacrificing trackpad input capabilities by choosing Mac hardware over another PC vendor (either due to hardware limitations or driver issues)?

Comment: I've edited this to be one question (and not three). I also edited out the part where you said "I searched the internet" since it doesn't help us help you. If you link to the article you found and explain why it doesn't help or at least give us the exact search terms you used - perhaps we can help locate reputable reviews of the Mac trackpad on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, if found that Windows runs great on my MBP 15''.
Drivers installation is very easy using Bootcamp.

Actually, a study [has shown](https://www.soluto.com/reports/pc-purchase-guide/2013-04) that MBP was the best performing laptop for running Windows operating system.

I would recommend to use a mouse on Windows. I am not very comfortable with the touchpad but it's more a personal thing, so you should give it a try and decide for yourself.

If you choose to buy a MBP retina and you connect to Internet using the Ethernet Thunderbolt adapter, be sure to connect it at boot time like described in [this other post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62283/are-boot-camp-drivers-for-thunderbolt-to-gigabit-ethernet-available/62287#62287).

Comment: I would second the opinion that Windows 7 and Boot Camp have decent trackpad drivers, but I don't run much in Windows other than to run some tests that I can't easily virtualize so I didn't want to answer myself that all was clear.