# Ethernet Adapter Windows Driver - how to find for BCM5701

Tags: windows, thunderbolt, ethernet

I am having troubles with finding driver for my [Apple Thunderbolt to Gigabit Ethernet Adapter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD463LL/A/thunderbolt-to-gigabit-ethernet-adapter).

I checked the version and I have a BCM5701 chip. [These](https://www.broadcom.com/support/ethernet-nic-netxtreme-i-desktop-mobile) Broadcom drivers don't support my adapter.

I want to get it working under my second PC Lenovo X1 Carbon with Windows 10 64-bit

Where can I find drivers to this ?

Comment: Can you please add more details about your setup? Are you running Windows via Bootcamp, within a VM or another way altogether? What makes you think you'll need a driver?

Comment: I try to use it on completly different computer, Lenovo X1 Carbon with win10 x64

Comment: Related: [Are Boot Camp drivers for thunderbolt to gigabit ethernet available?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62283/are-boot-camp-drivers-for-thunderbolt-to-gigabit-ethernet-available)

Answer (score 2):

**This is for Windows 7, but should work for Windows 10**

A quick search on the [Apple Support site](http://www.apple.com/shop/question/answers/product/MD463LL/A/will-windows-7-bootcamp-recognize-a-thunderbolt-ethernet-adapter/Q7AD2CYAKJ7X49X7A), I was able to find instructions on downloading the correct driver.  I have condensed them here for quick reference:

---

1. [Download the Netxtreme Mobile/Desktop Driver](https://docs.broadcom.com/docs/12358335).  **It will say that it's not supported, but the `.inf` file does include the requisite driver entries**
2. Unzip the drivers to a temporary folder on your hard drive (preferably your Desktop so it's easy to find)
3. Connect the adaptor to the thunderbolt port
4. Reboot Windows

Windows should automatically detect the adaptor now and install it. You may need to point the installer at the location where you unzipped the drivers.

If that doesn't work, you will need to do this through *Device Manager*

1. Go to Start > Control Panel > Hardware & Sound and open Device Manager
2. Click the name of your computer at the top of the device tree
3. Click Action at the top of the window and choose Add Legacy Hardware
4. Click Next
5. Select "Install hardware that I manually select..."
6. Choose Network Adaptors
7. Choose "Have Disk"
8. Browse to the location of the drivers you unzipped earlier.
9. Click the .inf file
10. Select Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet from the list of drivers available
11. OK and install

You may need to reboot again with the adaptor plugged into the Thunderbolt port to finish the job

**Note:  Again, these instructions and driver downloads are for Windows 7.  Thought they should work with Windows 10, it is not guaranteed.**

If having both OS X and Windows 10 support is important, consider getting a [USB 3.0 to Gigabit Ethernet Adapter](http://radnex.us/Anker_USB3-Gig-Ethernet_Adapter).  I have personnaly used this exact adapter on an iMac, a MacBook Pro, a Mac Mini (Dual Boot w/ Win 7) and a Surface Pro 3.

Comment: If anyone has a new link to the drivers (Broadcom does not allow to download them anymore) that would be great if they could share it somehow...

Comment: After #11, I'm getting "This device is not working properly because Windows cannot load the drivers required for this device. (Code 31)"